# Setting FreezePanes Property of the windows class -Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a huge application for importing and exporting which was written back in the version VBA 9.1 and **migrating** it to Excel 2013
I'm facing problem during the freezing of first row using this line.

```
AddWorksheetWithDefaults.Parent.Windows(1).Activate
With AddWorksheetWithDefaults.Parent.Windows(1)
.FreezePanes = False
.FreezePanes = True
End With
```

In this case I a''m getting error as **Unable to set FreezePanes Property of the windows class**

and the AddWorksheetWithDefaults is a method that returns a object().
"
I tried following

**Try 1**

```
AddWorksheetWithDefaults.Parent.Windows(1).Activate
With AddWorksheetWithDefaults.Parent.Windows(1).Rows("1:1").Select
.FreezePanes = False
.FreezePanes = True
End With
```

**Try 2**

```
AddWorksheetWithDefaults.Parent.Windows(1).Activate
With AddWorksheetWithDefaults.Parent.Windows(1).Rows(1).Select
.FreezePanes = False
.FreezePanes = True
End With
```

**Try 3**

```
AddWorksheetWithDefaults.Parent.Windows(1).Activate
With AddWorksheetWithDefaults.Parent.Windows(1).Rows("1:1")
.FreezePanes = False
.FreezePanes = True
End With
```

The options I tried gives me error as **property or method not found**

Help me out.

Comment: This will work: Open the programmers tab, start recording a macro, freeze panels as you need, stop recording. Then, look at the generated code. You will find the function invocation that you need.

Comment: Yes that I tried didn't help

Comment: But.... Don't you need to define the limits of the panel you wish to freeze? I mean, try to select a cell and then freeze. I think that the method `FreezePanels` is applicable to a WINDOW object, not to a specific cell. The  cell selection is to define where the freezing is to take place. Just guessing though...

Comment: To clarify, the worksheet you are trying to freeze the panes of resides in an instance of Excel 2013? Also, does it work to freeze panes manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
AddWorksheetWithDefaults.Parent.Windows(1).Activate
With AddWorksheetWithDefaults.Parent.Windows(1)
    .FreezePanes = False
    .SplitColumn = 0
    .SplitRow = 1
    .FreezePanes = True
End With
```